# Во всю Ивановскую

Tags: орфография, фразеология

На полную, во всю Ивановскую - так говорят. А что это за Ивановская? О чем вообще речь? А еще, подскажите, пожалуйста, нужно ли писать это слово с большой буквы?
Спасибо

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Это выражение связано с Московским Кремлем. Площадь в Кремле, на которой стоит колокольня Ивана Великого, называли Ивановской. На этой площади специальные люди-дьяки оглашали указы, распоряжения и прочие документы, касавшиеся жителей Москвы и всех народов России. Чтобы всем было хорошо слышно, дьяк читал очень громко, кричал во всю Ивановскую.

Comment: А писать-то как?

Comment: Так ведь понятно, что это название площади - с большой, прописной.

Answer (score 1):

Есть ещё одна версия, довольно распространённая: на той же Ивановской площади наказывали кнутом или плетьми осуждённых; естественно, они тоже очень громко кричал - "во всю ивановскую". Я предполагаю, что, в силу того, что первоначальное значение практически утрачено, и оборот речи стал единым целым, то "ивановскую" следует писать с маленькой буквы.

Answer (score 0):

Выражение (фразеологизм) "Кричать во всю Ивановскую" значит очень громко кричать.